# Django-summernote works properly, but shows text with HTML tags

Tags: python, django, rich-text-editor, summernote

Recently, I decided to use Django-summernote to edit model-form text fields. I can use the editor without any problem. When it comes to rendering output of the text edited with this tool, it displays with html tags. Looked around a while but not found any solution.

Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you're including the `|safe` filter on the content (and that you trust the content to be, in fact, safe).